# Definição de EJB

Tags: java, ejb, jee

Perdoem-me pelo assunto genérico, mas tenho pesquisado há tempos em diversos lugares e não encontrei nada que explicasse satisfatoriamente o que de fato é um EJB e para que serve.

Eu sou adepto do uso de exemplos reais em tudo para um melhor entendimento e encontrei poucos adeptos desse estilo nos tutoriais que vi. Geralmente dizem que EJB é [essencialmente um componente gerenciado que é criado, controlado e destruído pelo container gereciador do J2EE que estiver sendo executado](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-ejb/21253). Isso não me diz nada ou muito pouco. Na verdade saí do texto com mais dúvidas que antes.

Procurando mais, consegui entender que EJBs são módulos autônomos que recebem requisições e retornam respostas, como um método qualquer, com a vantagem de que podem ser invocados de aplicações externas. Está correto isso?

Um exemplo simples e prático seria um EJB que recebe o CPF de um cliente consulta se ele está aprovado ou não para realizar uma compra com cheque. Dentro desse EJB haveriam diversas regras de negócio (tempo de conta, ocorrências nos órgãos protetores de crédito, etc), até mesmo consultas a outros EJBs, com o objetivo de "puxar a ficha" do cliente e por fim retornar um SIM ou NÃO para quem o invocou. Esse EJB poderia ser utilizado por qualquer *client*: um aplicativo de celular, web ou desktop.

Alguém tem algo mais a acrescentar?

Porém, tenho algumas dúvidas: qual a diferença de um EJB para um WebService? (esse último sim sei o que é e já usei diversas vezes).

Qual a relação do JPA com o EJB? Já fiz diversas aplicações usando o Hibernate, que é um framework JPA. Isso significa que eu usei EJB?

Obrigado!

Comment: Ficarei contente se essa pergunta tiver respostas que não se limitem a _"EJBs têm as características A, B, C"_ mas também incluam _"A característica A serve serve para tal coisa, B tem utilidade tal"_, enfim, que não se limitem a definir mas esclareçam por que em uma aplicação com EJBs eles sejam considerados indispensáveis, em comparação a uma aplicação sem os mesmos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Sobre EJB

Definindo de modo rápido EJB é: "O cara para cuidar da regra de negócios".

Ele foi criado para controlar a transação, mensagens, segurança do projeto, etc.

As características do EJB são:

- Permitem injeção: eles podem ser injetados ou terem outros componentes injetados dentro deles
- Controle de segurança: basta anotar seu EJB ele estará protegido de acesso indevido
- Controle de transação: você pode controlar como a transação deve funcionar, tanto de modo automático como me modo programático

Existem alguns tipos de EJB que rapidamente podemos definir:

- Stateles: respondem apenas a uma chamada e logo depois podem ser utilizados para outras chamadas de qualquer cliente. O servidor cria um pool desse cara para caso a demanda aumente/diminua o servidor possa controlar a quantidade instâncias ativas. Eles também podem ser utilizados como WebServices, basta colocar uma anotação e pronto. [=
- Stateful: esse cara funciona como o HttpSession enquanto a referência continue viva. Geralmente esse cara é colocado dentro do HttpSession do usuário, desse modo quando o HttpSession morrer ele também morrerá. Honestamente nunca utilizei e nunca vi muita utilidade para ele
- Singleton: um EJB que só terá uma instância para todo o projeto. Ideal para ser utilizado na camada de DAO, por exemplo.
- MDB: Serviço de mensagens. Quase igual a um Stateles sendo a diferença que ele não pode ser chamado diretamente, mas apenas quando uma mensagem chega por um provedor de mensagens.

EJB é uma especificação, para poder utilizá-lo você precisa de um servidor como JBoss, Glassfish, TomEE...

Antes da versão 3.1 você precisava empacotar seu EJB dentro de um JAR e anexar o jar junto com seu WAR dentro de um EAR. Se você não empacotasse todo mundo dentro de um EAR seus EJBs teriam que ser do tipo Remoto. Um EJB remoto utiliza RMI para conexão o que tem impacto na performance. Quando um EJB estava dentro de um EAR ele poderia ser utilizado como Local, aí melhora a performance e outros aspectos.

### WebService + EJB

WebService em pouclas palavras é: expor um serviço para a web e nada mais. Ao utiliza apenas o WebService você poderá receber um Request de qualquer lugar do mundo. Um EJB pode expor um método para a web como um WebService e ainda ter todos os seus benefícios. Sem o EJB será necessário utilizar outro meio para controlar transação, segurança, timer, etc.

Uma vez que EJB é uma implementação JEE ele já vem em servidores e são bem fáceis de começar a utilizar (digo das versões mais novas, as mais antigas são complicadas).

### Finalizando

Ele não é um WebService, mas pode ter serviços expostos como Webservices. Controlam a transação e com isso se torna o lugar ideal para se colocar as regras do negócio. Tem serviço de mensagens, timer e outros.

Comment: Boa explicação, está ficando mais claro, mas ainda não entendi qual a vantagem sobre um webservice. Encontrei esse link http://www.universidadejava.com.br/docs/criandoumwebservicecomejb30 que me confundiu mais ainda. Se são coisas diferentes, como é que se pode criar um webservice COM ejb?

Comment: Adicionei um tópico WebService + EJB para responder sua pergunta

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de implementação de um EJB?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, não vou te dar uma resposta gigante, porque já existem centenas de fontes:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnblt.html)

Minha resposta:
"Qualquer classe anotada com `@Stateless`, `@Stateful` ou `@Singleton` que roda dentro de um Application server", isso é um EJB.

Porque EJB ?

"Suporte a transação, gerenciamento de ciclo de vida, Injeção de dependência, segurança, accesso remoto e local... e muito mais. Tudo isso gerenciado pelo container". Se você sabe oque são esses conceitos, até aqui você já deverá ter entendido oque é e o porque usar. Caso não saiba muito ao certo oque são, ou como um Servidor de aplicação(JBoss, Websphere, Glassfish, etc etc) funciona, te aconselho antes dar uma boa olhada sobre assuntos básicos sobre web application e/ou enterprise application
Um "MÓDULO" EJB é um arquivo .jar (que possuem POJOs, EJBs, etc etc) que pode ou não fazer parte de um arquivo maior (.ear) e roda dentro de um Servidor de aplicação.

Abraços

Answer (score 1):

O que me fez entender realmente foi este site:

http://entjavastuff.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/ejb-transaction-management-going-deeper.html

Para deixar a ideia mais concreta, o artigo foca num só aspecto dos EJBs:

- Transações

Isso inclui transações com o banco de dados (ou com mais de um banco de dados) e envio de mensagens. E nesse ponto, um método transacional do EJB realmente fica muito mais simples de escrever do que tentar tratar todas as possibilidades de commit e rollback na base do try/catch/finally.

É claro que existem outras funcionalidades nos EJBs (chamadas remotas, assíncronas, timers, mensagens, pooling de objetos, injeção de dependências, interceptors, segurança), e muitos materiais dão uma ênfase exagerada em chamadas remotas, e daí deve vir a confusão com web services...