# O que é e para que serve um Java Bean?

Tags: java, java-bean

Estou começando a ler sobre desenvolvimento [java](/questions/tagged/java) em camadas, e li alguma coisa a respeito sobre o bean, uma classe encapsulada.

Mas não encontrei nenhum conteúdo que realmente explicasse a finalidade e um exemplo.

Então, *o que é e para que serve um Bean?*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bom não ficou muito específico sobre o que exatamente você está falando, caso a resposta não seja exatamente o que você precisa, por favor especifique.

> O que é e para que serve um Bean ?

Em resumo:

- Uma classe que contenha todos os atributos privados
- Possua getters e setters para seus atributos
- Usada para encapsular e abstrair uma entidade
- Implementa `java.io.Serializable`

JavaBean é uma classe extremamente simples, o exemplo abaixo reflete um "Usuário" em algum sistema. Ou seja, ela é apenas uma classe que possui apenas atributos e seus respectivos getters e setters... em geral não possui nenhuma lógica adicional.

Não confundir com ***[Bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijsz.html)***, que é um componente da especificação de EJB (Enterprise Java Bean) do Java EE

**Exemplo:**

```
    public class Usuario {

    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private int idade;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

Note que existe uma convenção na nomenclatura dos métodos getters e setters. [Aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) você encontra mais detalhes sobre a nomenclatura padrão.

**Edit*****

> Ok, isso é um Bean, mas para que ele serve, qual sua função ?

Um JavaBean representa uma entidade (ou unidade ou modelo) do sistema (UML aqui!). Ele encapsula as informações necessárias a serem transportadas ao longo das camadas ou módulos.  Em outros casos também mapeia essas entidades com o banco de dados, vide [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), ou também em integrações entre aplicações (Web services [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) por exemplo).

Resumindo todos os dados necessários em um lugar só.

Para entender melhor, é necessário pensar mais como modelagem de sistemas ao invés de programação em si:

```
//Ok, eu sei que na instância de 'user' eu tenho todas as informações
//necessárias e encapsuladas ao meu modelo(entidade) "USUÁRIO".
Usuario user = new Usuario();
```

Caso não seja exatamente o que procura, é só retornar.

Comment: Ok, isso é um Bean, mas para que ele serve?

Comment: Entendi o que é, mas quero entender agora qual a sua finalidade, pra que serve?

Comment: Obrigado @Math... João Neto, veja se atende às suas dúvidas.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Estou meio atrasado, mas há alguma diferença para o ManagedBean?

Comment: @Patrick ManagedBean acredito que você esteja se referindo as annotations: `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`, `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` que são um assunto à parte do tratado aqui, neste caso, o mais proximo do assunto:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20706/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-ejb/20817#20817

Em geral o ManagedBean é um termo utilizado mais em JSF.

Comment: @Josue creio que faltou o construtor explicito

Answer (score 2):

Também acho o termo bean (grão, em português) um tanto obscuro. No Java o trocadilho se justifica, já que os beans representam os elementos a partir dos quais o produto (café, no caso) é feito.

[Eric Evans](https://twitter.com/ericevans0) propõe uma linguagem mais simples para o universo de desenvolvimento de software. Para ele, a linguagem [ubíqua](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) (onipresente, a que todos falam) é base para que todos entendam o sistema. Assim, de forma a facilitar o entendimento, chama um grupo de beans de Domínio (ou Modelo) e cada bean é uma Entidade. Como já foi dito, os beans são úteis para representar o core do negócio, ou seja, os elementos sobre os quais é vital gerenciar informação.

Answer (score 1):

Simplificando a forma de explicação, o padrão JavaBean, nada mais é do que as classes que modelam objetos, onde, obrigatoriamente, os atributos são declarados privados, que haja um construtor público padrão, e tem que ter os métodos acessores(getters e setters) públicos para cada atributo, e somente isso. Como o exemplo da Classe Usuario.java;

```
public class Usuario {

    private Long idUsuario;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private Integer idade;

    public Usuario(){
    }

    public Long getIdUsuario(){
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(Long idUsuario){
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz esse exemplo usando o Java, mas pode ser utilizado em outras linguagens como o PHP e C#