# Como pegar dados de uma JTable para armazenamento em um banco de dados?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Eu estou a desenvolver um projecto chamado Lista de Cardápio com um banco de dados MySQL e em Java no NetBeans, com uma biblioteca adicionada de MySQL-Connector-Java. Eu quero que os nomes dos produtos selecionados, a quantidade de produtos e o preço total do modelo `Cardapio.java` sejam armazenados e impressos como texto num banco de dados pelo modelo `Cadastro.java`, conectando-se com os modelos `Conexão.java` e `Teste.java`.

Ainda não resolvi dois erros no Java.

Siga o código-fonte completo do `Cardapio.java`:

```
package br.com.cardapio.view;

/**
-- Autor: Gustavo Benedito Costa
-- Curso: Ciência da Computação
-- Disciplina: Análise de Programação Orientada a Objectos
-- Professor: Carlos Feichas
-- Ano: 2ºA
-- Semestre: 3º Semestre

***GEORGIANO*** — ***GEORGIAN*** — ***ქართული***
-- ავტორი: გუშტავუ ბენედიტუ კოსტა
-- კურსი: კომპიუტერული მეცნიერება
-- დისციპლინური: ორიენტირებული პროგრამირება ანალიზი ობიექტები
-- მასწავლებელი: კარლოს
-- წელი: მეორე წელს A
-- სემესტრი: მესამე სემესტრი
 **/

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import br.com.control.Cadastro;

public class Cardápio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double valorTotal=0;    //valor dos pedidos
    DefaultTableModel tab1; // model da tabela Lanches
    DefaultTableModel tab2; //  model da tabela Lanches Selecionados

    public Cardápio() {
        initComponents();
        Tprodutos(); // inicializa a tabela Lanches
    }

    public void Tprodutos(){
        ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList(); // lista dos produtos
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList(); // lista dos preços

        t.add("X-salada");t.add("Mini pizza");t.add("Hamburguer");t.add("Suco de laranja"); t.add("Cappuccino"); // inserção de valores nas listas
        s.add("4.00");    s.add("3.25");       s.add("5.30");       s.add("5.00");          s.add("3.30"); //

        tab1=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();    // model da tabela
        //tab1.setNumRows(0);               <-- limpa a tabela
        int b=t.size(); // numero de tuplas na tabela

        for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
        {               //ok
            String produto = t.get(i); // pegar o nome do produto
            String valor = s.get(i);   // pegar o valor do produto
            tab1.addRow(new String[]{produto,valor});    // inserção de valores na tabela
        }
    }

    public String[] pega_dadosT1() throws SQLException{
        String[] a=new String [2];  // armazenar resultado
        String produto = "";        
        String valor = "";
        int indiceLinha = jTable1.getSelectedRow();  // pegar o indice da linha selecionada        
        if(jTable1.getRowCount()>0){ // numero de linhas > 0
        if (indiceLinha!=-1)
        {
             a[0] = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(indiceLinha,0); //pegar valor(linha , primeira coluna)
             a[1] = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(indiceLinha,1); //pegar valor(linha , segunda coluna)
             //obs: o indice das colunas sempre começa no numero 0
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Selecione um lanche da tabela Lanches!!!");// mensagem de erro
        }
        }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sem lanches Disponiveis!!!");}        // mensagem de erro
        return a; // retona vetor
    } 

    public void TprodutoSelecionado(String nomeP,String q,String v){
        double valor=Double.parseDouble(v); //conversão de String pra Double
        int quant=Integer.parseInt(q);  //conversão de String pra Inteiro

        valor=valor*quant;  // 

        tab2=(DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel(); // Model
        tab2.addRow(new String[]{nomeP,""+quant,""+valor}); // Add tuplas
        valorTotal=valorTotal+valor;    // Valor total dos pedidos
        jLValorTotal.setText(""+valorTotal); // inserindo valor no label(Valor Total: )
    }

    public void Tdelet_prodSelec(){                
        int indiceLinha = jTable2.getSelectedRow();  
        double valorProd=0;
        if(jTable2.getRowCount()>0){
            if (indiceLinha!=-1)
            {
                valorProd= Double.parseDouble(""+jTable2.getValueAt(indiceLinha, 2));
                           //converter        // converter e pela valor
                valorTotal=valorTotal-valorProd; // atualizar valor total
                jLValorTotal.setText(""+valorTotal); // atualizar label
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel()).removeRow(indiceLinha); // remover da tabela
            }
            else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Selecione um lanche da tabela dos lanches selecionados!");//
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tabela Lanches selecionados está vazia");// 
        }
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        JBAdicionar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLValorTotal = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Confirmacao = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(224, 237, 235));
        jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 300));
        jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 300));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(551, 300));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Produtos", "Valor"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(50);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
        }

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 40, 230, 124));

        jTable2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Produtos", "Q", "Valor"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable2.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);
        if (jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(30);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(30);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(30);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(50);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);
            jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(50);
        }

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 40, 230, 124));

        JBAdicionar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        JBAdicionar.setText("Adicionar");
        JBAdicionar.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JBAdicionar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JBAdicionarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(JBAdicionar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(270, 70, 101, 30));

        jBDelete.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jBDelete.setText("Deletar");
        jBDelete.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jBDelete.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 29));
        jBDelete.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 29));
        jBDelete.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 29));
        jBDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jBDelete, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(270, 110, 101, 30));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Valor Total:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(510, 170, -1, -1));

        jLValorTotal.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLValorTotal.setText("0.0");
        jPanel1.add(jLValorTotal, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 170, 50, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(67, 159, 137));
        jLabel3.setText("Lanches:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 20, -1, -1));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(67, 159, 137));
        jLabel4.setText("Lanches selecionados:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 20, -1, -1));

        Confirmacao.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(132, 196, 196));
        Confirmacao.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        Confirmacao.setText("Confirmar");
        Confirmacao.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Confirmacao.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 30));
        Confirmacao.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 30));
        Confirmacao.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 30));
        Confirmacao.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(101, 30));
        Confirmacao.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ConfirmacaoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(Confirmacao, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(270, 210, 101, 30));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 650, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void JBAdicionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        try {
            String prod[]=pega_dadosT1(); // "pega_dadosT1"
            String nome=prod[0];
            String valor=prod[1];
            String quant;

            if (nome!=null){ // 
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(); // cria um spinner 
                spinner.setValue(1); // inicializar com 1
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner, "Quantidade/Porção", WIDTH);// adionando o spinner a mensagem
                //obs: não consegui add o spinner ao ...showInputDialog.. fica 2 campos na tela, ou seja, não tem botão cancelar
                quant=""+spinner.getValue(); //            
                TprodutoSelecionado(nome,quant,valor);//
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cardápio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                           

    private void jBDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Tdelet_prodSelec();//
    }                                        

    private void ConfirmacaoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        Confirmacao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {

                                    // jTable é incompatível com o método getText

                    Cadastro.cadastrar(tab2.getText(), jLValorTotal.getText());
                    tab2.setText("");
                    jLValorTotal.setText("");
                    System.out.println("Cadastrado");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Deu erro");
                }
            }
        });
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Cardápio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     */

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Confirmacao;
    private javax.swing.JButton JBAdicionar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBDelete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLValorTotal;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Na parte: onde tem dois erros nesse arquivo `Cardapio.java`:

```
private void ConfirmacaoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        Confirmacao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {

  // jTable2 ou tab2 são incompatíveis com o método getText

                    Cadastro.cadastrar(tab2.getText(), jLValorTotal.getText());
                    tab2.setText("");
                    jLValorTotal.setText("");
                    System.out.println("Cadastrado");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Deu erro");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Eu uso `tab2` (variável do componente table) ou `jTable2` (variável do componente JTable) para pegar o nome dos produtos dos Lanches Selecionados para armazená-los num banco de dados e imprimi-los.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os erros seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Num arquivo `Cadastro.java`:

```
package br.com.control;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.cardapio.view.Conexao;

public class Cadastro {
    public static void cadastrar(String produtos, String quantidade, String prestacao) throws SQLException{
        Conexao classeConexao = new Conexao();
        Connection c = classeConexao.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        String query = "insert into cadastrofiscal values (?,?,?)";
        stmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, produtos);
        stmt.setString(2, quantidade);
                stmt.setString(3, prestacao);
        System.out.println(query);
        stmt.executeUpdate();


    }
}
```

No arquivo `Conexao.java`:

```
package br.com.cardapio.view;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexao {

    Connection con = null;
    private static Conexao instance = null;

    public Conexao() {
        inicio();
    }

    public void inicio() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver Carregado");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("O driver do Mysql n�o p�de ser carregado!");
        }
    }

    public static Conexao getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Conexao();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            if ((con == null) || (con.isClosed())) {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/agenda", "root", "");
                System.out.println("Conex�o Estabelecida");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

No arquivo `Teste.java`:

```
package br.com.cardapio.view;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class Teste {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Conexao c = new Conexao();
        Connection con = c.getConnection();

    }
}
```

Num arquivo SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE cardapiofiscal;
USE cardapiofiscal;

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `cadastrofiscal` (
  `produtos` TEXT COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `quantidade` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  `prestacao` INT(5) NOT NULL
);

insert into cadastrofiscal values ('X-salada, Suco de Laranja','2', '9.00');

select * from cadastrofiscal;
```

Agora, quero apenas que `tab2`ou `jTable2` (table ou JTable) sejam pegos como texto pelo `getText` para armazená-los no banco de dados. Mas esses são incompatíveis com o `getText` porque parece que não são String(s). Por isso, tenho que encontrar os métodos dessas variáveis desses componentes.

Comment: Isso ta parecendo erro semântico. `tab2` é um JTable?

Comment: @diegofm Não, `tab2` é um "`table`" e está dentro da jTable2 que é um Veja a imagem: http://i.imgur.com/Z3XCchf.png

Comment: Nunca vi componente "table" no java. Só conheço JTable. Adicione um [mcve] para que seja possivel avaliar melhor o problema.

Comment: @diegofm Actualizei a pergunta e completei, não sei se ficou melhor.

Comment: Na verdade tab2 e tab1 são models, não tables, como você disse.

Comment: O que é model? Tem como fazer isso para pegar os nomes dos produtos para armazená-los num banco de dados?

Comment: Você quer pegar os dados da segunda tabela?

Comment: Sim, exactamente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe [**DefaultTableModel**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) não possui o método `getText()`. Para recuperar linhas e colunas selecionadas, você deve usar o método [`getValueAt​(int row, int column)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt-int-int-), passando o número da linha e da coluna da `JTable` que você quer recuperar os dados.

É sempre interessante usar um [**Bean**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-um-java-bean) para guardar os dados antes de sair passando eles entre métodos, facilita o entendimento e manutenção do seu código.

Ex.:

```
public class Produto {

    private String nome;
    private double valor;
    private int quantidade;

    public int getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }
}
```

Daí, bastaria popular um produto por linha, antes de passar pro cadastro. Você pode passar uma lista de produto pro cadastro também:

```
    ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    int totalRows = suaJtable.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        Produto p = new Produto();
        p.setNome((String) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0));
        p.setValor((double) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2));
        p.setQuantidade((int) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3));

        produtos.add(p);
    }
```

Depois é só passar `produtos` para seu método de cadastro, e fazer um laço percorrendo a lista para pegar os produtos e inserir na tabela, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
for(Produto p : produtos){
    Cadastro.cadastrar(p.getNome(), p.getQuantidade(), p.getValor());
}
```

Implementado no seu código, ficaria algo assim:

```
private void ConfirmacaoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        Confirmacao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {

                    ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
                    int totalRows = suaJtable.getRowCount();

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                        Produto p = new Produto();
                        p.setNome((String) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0));
                        p.setValor((double) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2));
                        p.setQuantidade((int) suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3));

                        produtos.add(p);
                        }

                       //...

                    for(Produto p : produtos){
                        Cadastro.cadastrar(p.getNome(), p.getQuantidade(), p.getValor());
                    }

                    jLValorTotal.setText("");
                    System.out.println("Cadastrado");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Deu erro");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Talvez seja até mais interessante você [**criar seu próprio model**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595), dessa forma, ficará menos complicado desde popular sua tabela, até atualizar e capturar dados dela.

Comment: `ArrayList<Produto>(...)` e `for(Produto p : produtos)`são para o modelo `Cardápio.java` ou `Produto.java`?

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta essa ArrayList é pra você armazenar os produtos da tabela. Você pode fazer sem ela, passando direto no primeiro for, mas dessa forma, da pra adicionar algum tipo de validação ou checar algo nos produtos, antes de salvá-los. Os dois laços podem ser feitos seguidos na classe Cardapio.

Comment: Então quero adicionar. Mas esquecemo-nos da parte de `private void ConfirmacaoActionPerformed`. Então devo remover essa parte do código? Em qual parte da classe `Cardápio` coloco esses dois laços? Devo criar uma nova classe TableModel como a resposta sugeriu na questão que você postou?

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta você pode colocar no seu `actionPerformed` mesmo, já que é la que você precisa pegar os produtos e cadastra-los. Quanto ao TableModel, foi só uma dica. Só remova aquelas duas linhas no seu `try`, antes da linha `jLValorTotal.setText("");`. Veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: Ficou assim: http://i.imgur.com/5s0Beos.png? Apesar disso, um erro avisou que `p` já é definido e outro erro disse que os tipos incompatíveis não podem converter `int` para `String`.

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta veja o código da edição que fiz com seu actionPerformed, nesse seu você colou um laço dentro do outro, e o segundo nem foi fechado. Outro detalhes, você está guardando quantidade e valor como String no seu banco? Como você vai somar isso se precisar depois? Dá uma revisada nisso.

Comment: Eu corrigi, mas deu um erro quando eu executei o aplicativo e confirmei o cadastro. `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.sql.SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement at br.com.cardapio.view.Cardápio$6.actionPerformed(Cardápio.java:305)`. O que significa esse erro? Quanto às perguntas, sim, mas eu não consegui por causa desse erro. Eu não entendi a pergunta. Se você quiser dizer a quantidade e o valor. Então pego apenas a quantidade total e o preço total. Não separo as quantidades e os preços.

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta como você irá saber a quantidade de cada produto, se você guarda todos juntos numa linha? Talvez seja mais interessante você rever a modelagem do seu banco, senão sua aplicação pode ter problemas no futuro, e dificultar sua manutenção. O mais comum é ter uma tabela apenas pra armazenar produtos, outra pra armazenar pedidos feitos, e uma terceira pra guardar quais produtos e sua quantidade pedida em cada pedido.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que eu tenho que criar 3 novas tabelas a partir do zero?!

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta basicamente isso. Eu posso até adaptar o código para sua aplicação como tá, e você pode implementar e tudo fucionar, mas acredite, no futuro, você terá problemas se quiser, por exemplo, implementar controle de estoque, já que você não controla agora a quantidade de produtos que estão sendo vendidos. Você também não conseguirá recuperar pedidos isolados, já que não usa ID pra cada um.

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso e pelas informações. Estou perdido, porque o prazo do meu projecto expirará na próxima semana, pois terei de apresentar ao meu professor e aos clientes. Gastei 2 meses, construindo e reparando tantos erros da aplicação. Tem como eu adaptar tudo para a minha aplicação numa semana? Ou isso levará meses?

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta meio complicado responder isso, pois depende dos requisitos que lhe foram pedidos e da complexidade deles. Mas você pode tirar suas dúvidas aqui no [pt.so]  na medida em que elas forem surgindo, ou pesquisar sobre programas semelhantes e como funcionam também.

Comment: Fiz isso.Tem vários projectos prontos semelhantes ao meu projecto no GitHub, mas preciso ter um banco de dados nele porque meu professor pediu. Só não sei se esses projectos prontos semelhantes funcionam no Eclipse e NetBeans.

Comment: Quanto tempo você leva para adaptar uma aplicação num projecto muito pequeno igual a esse? O que falta mais no meu projecto? Tem como você adaptá-lo para meu projecto pronto (mas ainda um pouco incompleto)? Posso creditar você como autor e contribuidor se você quiser.

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta cara sinto muito mas não posso te ajudar :/ pegar um projeto assim já perto do fim para refatorá-lo quase que por completo exige muito tempo e estudo do caso. Em alguns casos, fazer do zero acaba sendo uma opção mais viável do que "consertar o que já está feito". É por esse risco e outros que podem surgir, e por demandar tempo(o meu está meio corrido ultimamente), até pelo seu prazo, vou ficar te devendo essa :/

Comment: Tudo bem, não tem problema, já mudei de projecto e substituí-o pelo de emissor de cupom fiscal o qual encontrei no vídeo do Youtube, com a permissão do meu professor.