# Como adicionar ao AbstractTableModel um combobox populado por informação do banco de dados?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Gostaria de saber se é possível implementar um `combobox` em um `AbstractTableModel` de maneira q o mesmo receba informações diretamente do banco de dados para o preenchimento. se possível alguém poderia me dar um exemplo?

Como sempre usei `DefaultTable`, eu não entendo muito sobre `AbstractTableModel`, e por isso da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

[`AbstractTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) é uma implementação abstrata que serve como base para se criar uma "modelagem" de dados em uma `JTable`, não tem relação alguma com combos.

Para modelar dados em JComboBoxes, você pode usar a classe [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html), que também é uma implementação de modelagem de dados, porém ela é concreta e geralmente atende a maioria das necessidades ao se usar combos, principalmente quando se vai preencher com tipos primitivos e Strings.

Se precisar de algo mais especifico que esta implementação não resolva, você precisa criar sua própria implementação, ou sobrescrever [a implementação do método `toString()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/28595) da classe que representará o objeto que populará o combo, depende da complexidade do que se quer fazer.

Nos links abaixo tem alguns exemplos de implementação:

- [Preencher JComboBox com um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105695/28595)
- [Popular JComboBox com Strings e IDs trazidos do banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204149/28595)

Eu costumo muito utilizar uma implementação genérica que criei, assim não preciso implementar um modelo para cada tipo de objeto criado que vou preencher um combo, mas para que ela funcionar corretamente, seu [bean](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22444/28595) precisa ter o método `toString()` sobrescrito. [**Neste link**](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples/ComboBoxModelTest.java) há um exemplo de implementação dela.

---

Relendo a pergunta, creio que a duvida possa estar relacionada também a como adicionar um combo ao editor de alguma célula/coluna numa tabela, e para isso, você não usará models, pois não se trata de uma alteração do modelo de preenchimento, e sim, da exibição de células da tabela, através da interface [`TableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html), que contém os métodos necessários para você criar uma forma personalizada de renderizar as células, e da interface [`TableCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html), que contém os métodos necessários para criar uma forma personalizada de se renderizar a célula quando entrar em modo de edição. Se quiser ler mais a respeito, recomendo os tutoriais oficiais da documentação: [*How to Use Tables*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) e [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).