# Alguem consegue explicar oque é uma bean do Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, java-bean

Alguem consegue simplificar oque é uma bean ? Eu ja li a descrição pelo site do proprio Spring mas não fez muito sentido (para mim) o que de fato ela é, e para que de fato ela serve.

Sei que tenho que configurar ela no spring-context.xml, mas não sei exatamente o porque, ou oque esta acontecendo na realidade, quero entender qual necessidade declarar esta Bean esta suprindo.

Abraços e agradecimentos antecipados. rs

Comment: Não sei se é duplicata de [O que é e para que serve um Java Bean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22444/28595) ou de [Definição de EJB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20706/28595)

Answer (score 1):

Um bean é um objeto que é criado, gerenciado e destruído pelo container do spring, o framework é totalmente responsável por este objeto, criando, injetando suas propriedades (Injeção de dependência). Podemos injetar este objeto no container (aplicação spring) através de declarações no xml (no seu caso, spring-context.xml) ou através de anotação, desta forma utilizamos o padrão de inversão de controle (*IoC - Inversion of Control)*. Não sei se ficou entendido. Grande abraço.

Para maiores informações, segue referência de [Inversion of Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) (Em Inglês).